# NGINX serves wrong site, inconsistently deepening on browsing location

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, wordpress

I've got this weird problem that I don't understand. 
I used the EE engine script to install a wordpress blog at linode, using NGINX. This has worked well in the past.

The script installs a VHOST for my domain name (let's call it example.com) and the end result in the /etc/nginx/sites-available is  :

- default
- example.com
- 22222 (admin tools, these are not the issue)

### The problem :

After setting up the DNS in linode everything seemed to work fine. Example.com pulled up the WordPress blog with no issues. However, at my office location, NGINX would revert back to default ! ... So, at home and everywhere else, there was no problem, while in some other locations (like the office), NGINX would give me the default index.xxx (with the NGINX is working message). Same, laptop, same browser, same everything, but different resolving, depending on which physical location I am in.

### Solution 1 :

Forcing NGINX to use example.com by making it default_server in the config. This works, however it should not HAVE to be the way to solve it, since NGINX should catch the domain name and serve correct site. How else can I trust it to serve the correct pages whenever I setup more sites on it in the future ?

### Solution 2 :

The file : etc/nginx/sites-enabeled/default has the following lines :

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        # ......
```

Whenever I comment out the second listen directive, namely :

```
listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

And I leave the first one in, then NGINX resolves my domain name CORRECTLY, while /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default is STILL the default_server.

This seems to be CORRECT behavior, am I right ?

### The question:

So, now I would like to know if this is really the correct behavior, why this is so, and if this has been a bug or just a misconfiguration.

**Bug ??? :** because with the original config (including the second directive), NGINX used to revolve correctly from my house, but NOT from my workplace location (same laptop, browser, etc, etc,). Inconsistent

**Mis-config ????** : You tell me why that is so, when before it used to not resolve correctly only from my workplace ...

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that you don't have an IPv6 `listen` directive in the `example.com` server config but use IPv6 to access the site in the locations where it doesn't work.

In that case, the `listen [::]:80 default_server;` directive catches the request, as there is nothing matching for `example.com`. If you remove this line, the server falls back to IPv4 entirely and everything works.

The correct solution in that case would be to add `listen [::]:80` to the `example.com` server stanza.